# WPF - binding property to user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I'm having trouble passing a value from one user control to a dependency property on a child user control.  I think my issue might lie somewhere within the data context, but I've spent quite a bit of time searching stackoverflow and trying different tweaks to the bindings and data context and can't get this working.  The snippet below shows what works and what doesn't.  I can successfully bind the parent property to a label, and I can successfully pass a hard-coded value to the child user control, but I cannot pass the parent property binding to the user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyParentUC.MyParentUC_View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyParentUC"
             xmlns:MyChildUC="clr-namespace:MyChildUC;assembly=MyChildUC"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="{Binding MyInteger}" /> <!-- works -->
        <Grid>
            <MyChildUC:ChildUC VerticalAlignment="Top" MyInteger="{Binding Path=MyInteger}" /> <!-- doesn't work -->
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <MyChildUC:ChildUC VerticalAlignment="Top" MyInteger="123" /> <!-- works -->
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: A common mistake would be that ChildUC sets its own DataContext. Which data binding error message do you observe in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the program?

Comment: ChidUC was setting its own data context.  I removed that, and set the data context in a StackPanel within ChildUC, and now it seems to work. Thank you! :)